# PowerBuilder dropdowndatawindow insertrow changes Display Column value

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

Working with PowerBuilder 11.5.

I have a datawindow (dw) consuming a dropdowndatawindow (dddw). I am performing dddw.insertrow (0) in the constructor of the dw, and then doing dw.insertrow().

The issue I am having is that the value of "Display Column" for the dddw control in the dw is being changed to the value of the "Data Column" at some point, i.e. the resulting application is showing the data (primary key) instead of a formatted string value (the "Display Column" I had selected).

I am also retrieving the value of the "Display Column" property after the insertrow and retrieve calls, and it is still defined as I had set it initially (i.e. unchanged), however when the data is displayed, the "Data Column" values are shown.

Any pointers to why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the value of the column in dw actualy matches a value of a line in the dddw? Do you make some dynamic filtering in the dddw?

Comment: Is the dddw retrieving any rows? what's in it when you drop it down?

Comment: @HughBrackett Yes. I solved the issue by eliminating the dddw altogether, and displaying one value in a Column control (text box).

Answer (score 1):

PB shows "Data" instead of "Display" when it can't find **exact** match of DW's value to DDDW's data.

Thought, your "Data column" has "char(...)" type?

One of possible solution - switch to numeric (I prefere "long") type instead of strings as "Data". PB much more precise with numbers.

Comment: Why would not string data match instead of numeric?

Comment: The "Data column" is of type long, the "Display column" is a string (computed field). The thing is that the dw's value is passed to the dddw and the dddw's SELECT statement retrieves the corresponding record, yet the dddw still shows the "Data column" instead of the "Display column".

Comment: @Alex Tabone, I don't use autoretrieved DDDW's. Imho, preferred method is to insert new rows in DDDW before changing the item in DW.

Comment: @Seki, don't know. But I've encountered this weird behavior several times and have switched to numeric data types.

Comment: @Maximus Disabling the Autoretrieve property on the control (both when pre-inserting a row and not pre-inserting a row in the dddw) is giving the same behavior, i.e. displaying the "Data column" (long) instead of the "Display column" (string).

Comment: @Maximus Solved the issue by eliminating the dddw, and instead displaying one value in a Column control (text box). I am filling the Column control through SQL using dw.setitem. Unfortunately could not find a proper solution. Thanks all for ur help.